# Changing CSS with JS Object Orientated Programming

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, oop

I want to change the CSS values of spans through OOP JS.

The mouse hovers over a photo, and the main body of text 'changes' i.e. one span disappears and the other appears.

```
$(Document).ready(function(){
    $('#blackSquare').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#originalContent').css('display', 'none');
        $('#photo').css('display', 'table-cell');
    });
    $('#blackSquare').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#photo').css('display', 'none');
        $('#originalContent').css('display', 'table-cell');
    });
});
```

I need to do the above code for each object I want affect the css. Is there an easy OOP way of doing this?

Comment: what do u mean by OOP JS

Comment: @AhsanShah: What's unclear about OOP JS? JavaScript using object-oriented techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Not so much *OOP*, but basically you have two choices:

1. If there's any kind of structural relationship between the element the mouse is interacting with and the ones you want to show/hide (parent/child, sibling, sibling of parent twice removed, whatever), then you start with `$(this)` (a jQuery wrapper around the element the mouse is interacting with) and use the [various traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) to finds the ones you want to show/hide.

   For example, let's say for the sake of argument that `blackSquare`, `photo`, and `originalContent` are all within a container with the class `container`. Let's also say that `photo` and `originalContent` are *classes* rather than `id`s. Then:

   ```
   $('#blackSquare').mouseenter(toggleContent.bind(undefined, true));
   $('#blackSquare').mouseleave(toggleContent.bind(undefined, false));
   function toggleContent(flag) {
       var container = $(this).closest('.container');
       container.find('.originalContent').css('display', flag ? 'none' : 'table-cell');
       container.find('.photo').css('display', flag ? 'table-cell' : 'none');
   }
   ```
2. If there isn't a structural relationship, you can store the `id`s of the elements to show/hide in `data-*` attributes on the element the mouse interacts with, then get those vaules via `$(this).attr("data-foo")` (for example) and use those in your show/hide selectors. (Or you could use `data`, but if all you're doing is reading `data-*` attributes, `data` is overkill.) So in your example code, for instance, you'd store the `id`s `photo` and `originalContent` on the `blackSquare` element. For example:

   ```
   $('#blackSquare').mouseenter(toggleContent.bind(undefined, true));
   $('#blackSquare').mouseleave(toggleContent.bind(undefined, false));
   function toggleContent(flag) {
       var $this = $(this),
           photoId = $this.attr("data-photo-id"),
           contentId = $this.attr("data-original-content-id");
       $('#' + photoId).css('display', flag ? 'none' : 'table-cell');
       $('#' + contentId).css('display', flag ? 'table-cell' : 'none');
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your basic jQuery approach here is fine and you don't need an OOP way of doing this.  Just use class selectors instead of ID selectors and the same code will cover all instances: e.g. you could change it to this to be more flexible:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.photo-area').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).find('.content').css('display', 'none');
    $(this).find('.photo').css('display', 'table-cell');
  });
  $('.photo-area').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).find('.photo').css('display', 'none');
    $(this).find('.content').css('display', 'table-cell');
  });
});
```

Note that you can have classes which are used purely as jQuery selectors i.e. have no CSS rules associated with them. Since you can assign multiple CSS classes to an element, you can use your 'functional' CSS class names for element selection and have separate ones for the styling. This way your functional selectors can be used in different scenarios where the styling could be quite different - this I think is the re-use that you would want to achieve.